# Synchronous DC-DC buck converter body diode switching loss

Tags: buck, switching, converter, loss

I have a couple of questions regarding the body diode of MOSFET.

I was looking at the calculation of the switching losses in the synchronous buck converter.

1. For calculating the turn-off switching losses of the body diode used in the buck converter, I need reverse recovery charge and reverse recovery time details. But when I look into the datasheet of the MOSFET datasheet FDMC86340, it specifies a table with the name drain to source diode characteristics reverse recovery time and reverse recovery charge time. I'm not sure these are characteristics of body diode or antiparallel connected diode. If this refers to an anti-parallel-connected diode, could someone suggest to me how to find the details of body diode characteristics?
2. I was referring to MOSFET power losses calculation using the dataheet parameters document from Infineon. In the document switching losses of the diode can be calculated using below formula.

EonD = (1/4)*(Qrr)*(UDD)

Where: Qrr: Reverse recovery charge, UDD is the supply voltage.

But if I look at the switching characteristics of the diode mentioned in the datasheet page 7, it is
[image]

This should lead to EDon = (1/2)*(Qrr)*(UDD)

Not sure why 1/2 is multiplied here.

I have attached the screenshot of the waveform for reference.
[image]

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: _"when I look into the datasheet of the MOSFET datasheet FDMC86340, it specifies a table with the name drain to source diode characteristics reverse recovery time and reverse recovery charge time. I'm not sure these are characteristics of body diode or antiparallel connected diode."_ - the FDMC86340 doesn't have an 'antiparallel connected diode' so it can't be that.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Oh ok. On page 2 of the datasheet, it had a Diode connected anti-parallel to MOSFET, so I thought the diode was present in that module. One more thing, how did you know that diode wasn't present, was mentioned anywhere in the Datasheet?